# How can I localize Visual Studio Code snippet's descriptions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am making snippets plugin in vscode, as follows

```json
  "Progress": {
    "prefix": ".progress",
    "body": "progress",
    "description": "Documentation and examples for using Bootstrap custom progress bars featuring support for stacked bars, animated backgrounds, and text labels."
  }
```

When users use it, they can see "description"
[image]

The point is that I want users in different countries to see their own language, how should I configure it, or where there are documents in this regard, thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. The documentation for VSC's snippets feature does not describe any way of localizing the content of `description`. Where are you seeing other extensions or snippets localize themselves?

Comment: I would assume that an extension that contains localizable snippets will generate the snippet JSON on-demand with the `description` prepopulated with the correctly localized content.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I want to make a localized "description", is there any related documentation, or other vscode plugins for reference